# Solicitação AJAX para PHP (CodeIgniter) não retorna valores

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Estou trabalhando em uma situação que não consigo resolver há mais de 2 dias seguidos.
Tenho um AJAX que está solicitando os valores para um controller para popular um select com as cidades. A solicitação parece estar (nenhum erro no debug), mas no entanto não vem nada no retorno.

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#selectEstado').change(function() {

    var uf = $('#selectEstado').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "busca/carregaCidades/" + uf,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

    });
});
```

Controller:

```
    public function carregaCidades($uf)
    {
        $resultado = $this->busca_model->getCidades($uf);
        return json_encode($resultado);
    }
```

Model:

```
    public function getCidades($uf)
    {
        $this->db->where('uf', $uf);
        $dados = $this->db->get('tb_cidades')->result();

        return $dados;
    }
```

Mesmo sem nenhum erro no console, o resultado da solicitação não vem.
Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: por acaso, se vc der um `var_dump` em `$dados` dentro do model vem alguma coisa? Ou se der um `echo $this->db->last_query();` para retornar a ultima query, quando vc roda ela no seu banco direto, pelo phpmyadmin por exemplo, dai roda certo e retorna alguma coisa?

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, Marcelo! Havia conseguido resolver, o problema era o retorno na controller... eu estava retornando o json do PHP para o jquery, logo, deveria ter usado o echo ao invés do return!

Comment: Que bom que resolveu o seu problema ai, agora o legal é como vc achou a solução, responda como resolveu para que futuros usuários tbm possam se beneficiar com sua questão.

Answer (score 2):

Amigo um único detalhe que você pecou foi que, ali no controller em vez de você da um `return json_encode($resultado);` você teria que fazer um `echo json_encode($resultado);` O ajax vai pegar o que o php 'imprimir na tela', e não se comunicar diretamente com ele, para você dar um return ele pegar o valor.

Controller:

```
public function carregaCidades($uf)
{
    $resultado = $this->busca_model->getCidades($uf);
    echo json_encode($resultado);
}
```

espero ter ajudado.